# PHP Calculation in variables from foreach output

Tags: php, math, foreach, calculator

I have this code:

```
$fookerdos = '';
foreach (glob("records/*/*/kerdos.txt") as $somekerdos) {
  $fookerdos .= file_get_contents($someposoA);
//to print them i you want
print $fookerdos;
```

So my problem that for this code will outputs many numbers becouse of many files.

for example will out output this

**3.5 -6.7 6.68 -0.2 and so on..**

now i want all this numbers to make them (**addition**)
i know how to addition some 2-3 variables, but i additions many numbers that I even dont know how many they are.

for example

```
print "3.5 + "-6.7" "6.68" "-0.2";
```

Thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does each file contain only a single number, or can they have more than one numbers?

From your previous edits, it seems as if one file contain only a number.

In that case, you can store the values in [an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and sum the numbers using [array_sum()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) or perform any other calculation as needed.

Here is a sample code for you:

```
$fookerdos = array ();
foreach (glob("records/*/*/kerdos.txt") as $somekerdos) {
   $fookerdos[] = file_get_contents($somekerdos);
}

echo array_sum ($fookerdos);
```

Comment: You need the `file_get_contents($somekerdos)`

Comment: sorry for the late to replace, i will check it out and i will accept you. thx.

Comment: each file contains kerdos.txt file contains now something like this " 6.68" or something like this "-6.6" and so on.

Comment: Oopss. Yes I forgot the `file_get_contents()`. Thank you @Michal Skrzypecki for pointing that out and @drrcknlsn for editing the code.